# Could you please provide an example of DispatcherOneToMany?

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I want to connect multiple WebRtcEndPoints to one filter, so I want to use DispatcherOneToMany with multiple HubPorts.

I build the pipeline like this:

PlayerEndpoint -> Customized GStreamer Filter -> HubPort –> DispatcherOneToMany -> HubPort -> WebRtcEndpoint

But it doesn't work, I can only see the video in the first browser connected to the WebRtcEndPoint.

I will appreciate it if someone can provide a demo.

Thank you very much!